# Join Two Tables and Show all the records

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to join two tables (view_sales_report and com_payments) and show all the records from view_sales_report. The query is below, but the problem its showing the records of only com_payments entry. I guess i need to change the where condition.

```
SELECT
view_sales_report.tender_id,
view_sales_report.customer_code,
view_sales_report.marketing_exe,
com_payments.main_section,
com_payments.amt_curr,
com_payments.amount,
com_payments.date_of_pay,
com_payments.cat_paid,
view_sales_report.category,
view_sales_report.po_received_date
FROM view_sales_report
JOIN com_payments ON com_payments.tender_id = view_sales_report.tender_id AND com_payments.main_section ='Incentives'
WHERE com_payments.cat_paid = 'Marketing'
ORDER BY view_sales_report.file_no DESC
```

Any one can pls help me on this?

Table view_sales_report

```
tender_id   | customer_code | 
1           | 0             | 
2           | 0             |
3           | 0             |
4           | 0             |
5           | 1             |
6           | 0             |
```

Table Com_Payments

```
tender_id   | main_section | cat_paid
1           |              | marketing
```

Desired Output

```
tender_id   | customer_code | cat_paid
1           | 0             | Marketing
2           | 0             |
3           | 0             |
4           | 0             |
5           | 1             |
6           | 0             |
```

The Output iam getting

```
tender_id   | customer_code | cat_paid
1           | 0             | Marketing
```

Comment: Show some sample data with the expected result

Comment: Pls check, i have added the desired output and the output iam getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join and add the where to the `on` clause

```
SELECT
view_sales_report.tender_id,
view_sales_report.customer_code,
view_sales_report.marketing_exe,
com_payments.main_section,
com_payments.amt_curr,
com_payments.amount,
com_payments.date_of_pay,
com_payments.cat_paid,
view_sales_report.category,
view_sales_report.po_received_date
FROM view_sales_report
LEFT JOIN com_payments ON com_payments.tender_id = view_sales_report.tender_id AND com_payments.main_section ='Incentives'
AND com_payments.cat_paid = 'Marketing'
ORDER BY view_sales_report.file_no DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Working fine.